# Biblatex and citation reset between chapters

Tags: biblatex, numbering, footnotes, citing, chapters

I have a feeling that there is an obvious answer to this question that I'm somehow managing to miss. However, I've tried most of the commands in the `biblatex` documentation and I still can't figure it out.

What I want to do is reset the count for my footnotes and citations between chapters. In addition I also want ibid's, opcit's etc to start again at the beginning of a new chapter.

I'm currently using XeLaTeX with `biblatex`. My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1=true,natbib=true,sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

%Additional Stuff that I don't think should influenec the bibliography, but is here just in case
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\setmainfont{Lyon Text Regular No. 2}
\setsansfont{Lyon Display Light}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\pretolerance=5000
\tolerance=1000 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Answer (score 12):

In the `book` class, footnotes (including citations as footnotes) *are* reset at the start of a new chapter by default. If it's different for you, you must be doing something your code snippet doesn't show. You could try to add the following to your document preamble (note that the starred version of `\counterwithin` doesn't add chapter prefixes):

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{chapter}
```

To reset "ibid." and similar expressions per chapter, use the `biblatex` package option `citereset=chapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,citereset=chapter]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text \autocite{B02}.

\chapter{bar}

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Having read that citations should automatically reset elsewhere I thought it must be something peculiar to me or a package class. However, I've just realized that it was because I was using \chapter*{Title} rather than \chapter{Title}.

Comment: @TimothyMonteath You're welcome! Please consider to upvote my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and possibly to accept it (by clicking on the checkmark).