# How to reset footnote numbering at \chapter* and at frontmatter chapters?

Tags: numbering, footnotes, chapters, starred-version, front-matter

A comment to my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53526/510) to [Biblatex and citation reset between chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53524/biblatex-and-citation-reset-between-chapters) made me realize that, contrary to normal chapters in the `book` and `report` class, `\chapter*` (the starred version) does not reset the numbering of footnotes:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Preface}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}

\chapter*{Introduction}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}

\chapter{First}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}

\end{document}
```

The same is true for `\chapter` in the frontmatter of the `book` class:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}

\chapter{Introduction}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote}

\end{document}
```

How to reset footnote numbering at `\chapter*` and at frontmatter chapters?

Comment: This would probably be easiest by patching the `\chapter` command.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I suspected so, but I'm not familiar with patching only the starred version of a command (the non-starred version `\chapter` works fine).

Comment: But it wouldn't harm setting the footnote counter to zero twice in immediate succession, would it?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Probably not, but I have been surprised by counter behaviour on another occasion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24822/resetting-theorem-counters-sections-and-missing-subsections

Comment: `\@makeschapterhead` typesets the title of "starred" chapters. See my answer.

Comment: Look again, edited. As the "reset" is just globally setting to 0, it's really no problem if it's done twice, as long as no footnote can slip between the two resets :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would patch `\@chapter` and `\@schapter` to set the `footnote` counter to zero; the first one will take care of the situation for `\chapter*` and the second one will take care of chapters created with `\chapter` under `\frontmatter` (the `chapter` counter is not reset under `\frontmatter` since
the definition for `\@chapter` starts with

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
```

and `\frontmatter` does

```
\@mainmatterfalse
```

So the patching would be something like

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Patching `\@chapter` will reset the footnote counter twice for *mainmatter* chapters (by yor patch plus by `\refstepcounter{chapter}` -- do you think this is insignificant?

Comment: I would use `\pretocmd`, otherwise there could be a problem with a footnote *inside* the chapter title.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: now it's my turn: darn! ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: No, I think it's not a problem.

Comment: It was hard to chose among the two answers, especially because both Stefan and you improved the other one's answer. I accepted Stefan's answer beccause its latest version works for `memoir` (both answers work for `KOMA-Script` classes).

Comment: Dang -- your answer works for memoir, too. So I accepted it instead, because you were the first to tackle the `\frontmatter` issue.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why not patching directly `\chapter`, then?

Answer (score 6):

As Gonzalo mentioned, it's not sufficient to only patch the macro to output the "starred" version of the chapterhead. So I suggest to patch `\chapter`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\chapter{\thispagestyle}{\global\c@footnote\z@\thispagestyle}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: +1. Is `\global` essential, or only a safety precaution?

Comment: @lockstep I just modeled it on the way it works in non-starred chapters. But even if it might work without `\global` in this case, it's never a good idea to handle counters with or without `\global` inconsistently. I bet David can explain why (something with retaining values).

Comment: But this won't solve the problem for `\frontmatter`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina darn, I looked at `report` ;-) See my edit.

Comment: Shouldn't one use the `xpatch` package for patching macros with optional arguments like `\chapter`?

Comment: @lockstep In this case, the optional argument handling it done by `\secdef` which comes after my patch. Inserting after `\thispagestyle{plain}` is really a good place because it comes after `\cleardoublepage`(no issues with held over material) at a time when global ressources are configured.

Comment: Is inserting `\global\c@footnote\z@` immediately *before*  `\thispagestyle` safe? This way, your solution would work with the `memoir`class -- its `\chapter` command uses `\thispagestyle{chapter}`.

Comment: @lockstep Yea, no problem. Good idea. Edited.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Sorry for accepting and unaccepting -- I should have tested more thouroughly.

Comment: @lockstep No problem. The best answer should be the accepted one to serve as a reference for people finding this question later.

Comment: @StephanLehmke `\setcounter{footnote}{0}` is precisely the same as `\global\c@footnote\z@`. Well, it also checks if the counter is defined, which it is. I'd advocate the LaTeX method.

Comment: @egreg Good idea in principle, but I have modeled this strictly after `\refstepcounter` which seemed to be safest, considering the original task. So I think it's a matter of taste in this special case ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Although both answers provided so far, solved the problem with the footnote counters, perhaps a better way is to define *semantic* commands for the additional front matter sections.

This is a much better approach than injecting material into the posterior or anterior of macros, with yet another package.

I have seen sections in front matter as Preface, Foreword, Acknowledgments, Series Editor's Preface, About this Book, List of Contributors, Definitions, Author Affiliations, Abbreviations, Declaration and many others, and that is in English books. These sometimes are also included in the Table of Contents. Some of them are signed and others have a variety of other formatting requirements. For this reason I prefer to set them as environments.

Here is a factory command for making such environments (solving the footnote problem as well) and enforcing consistency all in five lines of code and no need for any package.

```
\newcommand\forewordname{foreword}
\newcommand\definitionsname{Definitions}
\newcommand\makepreamblecmd[1]{%
    \expandafter\newenvironment\expandafter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \chapter*{#1}}% could be other formatting macro
{}}
```

You create the new environments so,

```
 \makepreamblecmd{\forewordname}
 \makepreamblecmd{\definitionsname}
```

By using macros such as `\forewordname` you also cater for languages other than English.

Here is a full minimal,

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\forewordname{foreword}
\newcommand\definitionsname{Definitions}
\newcommand\prefacename{Preface}
\newcommand\makepreamblecmd[1]{%
    \expandafter\newenvironment\expandafter{#1}{%
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
   \chapter*{#1}}%
{}}

\title{test}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\makepreamblecmd{\forewordname}
\makepreamblecmd{\definitionsname}
\makepreamblecmd{\prefacename}
\begin{foreword}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
\end{foreword}
\begin{Definitions}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
\end{Definitions}

\begin{Preface}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
\end{Preface}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
Some text.\footnote{A footnote}
\end{document}
```

One could modify the "factory method" that generates the environments to add the name to the ToC and to ensure it is hyperlinked, if required.