# Reset Autocite Footnote Counter Every Section in Article Class

Tags: numbering, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/continuous-v-per-chapter-section-numbering-of-figures-tables-and-other-docume)

I am trying to reset the \autocite footnote number counter every section in article class.  I know latex does this [automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/how-to-reset-footnote-numbering-at-chapter-and-at-frontmatter-chapters) with chapters when using the Book class.  I have also taken a look at the FAQ [counters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset) and [footnotes per page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footnpp) but I cannot think of how to do this myself.  I am using Bibtex and a MWE is below.

I would like \autocite[1-2]{MyKey} and \autocite[2-3]{MyKey2} to have the same footnote number after compiled, "1".  This is because they are both the first in their section, i.e. section is to article class as chapter is to book class.  Hopefully this helps.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand*{\textsubscript}[1]{$#1{}$}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references = {Works Cited}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\makeindex
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\ifcsname #1format\endcsname\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}
\def\sectionformat{}
\def\subsectionformat{}
\def\subsubsectionformat{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Part I}
    Hello World \autocite[1-2]{MyKey}
\newpage
\section{Part II}
hello new world \autocite[2-3]{MyKey2}
\newpage
\section{Part III}
    \end{document
```

Comment: It's quite unclear from the example what you want to obtain.

Comment: For example, when I use \autocite[1-2]{MyKey} it assigns a superscript number to the location in the text and the footnote below.  I would like to reset the counter after each section so that the footnote numbering starts at "1" each time. I added some code to try and help

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}` is what's needed.