# How to reset sidenote numbering in chapters? (Tufte-LaTeX)

Tags: numbering, footnotes, tufte

I've looked at this question:

[How to reset footnote numbering at \chapter* and at frontmatter chapters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/how-to-reset-footnote-numbering-at-chapter-and-at-frontmatter-chapters),

but the answers concern using `\chapter*`, and assume the OP is not using the `Tufte-LaTeX` package. I use `\chapter` to indicate the start of a new chapter in `Tufte-LaTeX`; my `sidenote` numbers are not reset between chapters, and I would like to do so.

Here is a MWE, using the first suggestion. Unfortunately the sidenote in chapter 2 starts at 2.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter% so we can use @ in the command name
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}% restart the sidenote counter for each chapter
\makeatother% resets the meaning of @

\begin{document}

\chapter{ONE}
TEST\sidenote{footnote \#1}

\chapter{TWO}
LOOK\sidenote{footnote \#2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset the sidenote counter each chapter, add the following lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \oldchapter
}
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% Generate some dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\sometext}{%
  Blah\sidenote{First sidenote.} \lipsum[1]\par
  Blah\sidenote{Second sidenote.} \lipsum[2]\par
}

% Reset the sidenote number each chapter
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\def\chapter{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \oldchapter
}

\begin{document}

% Regular chapter
\chapter{First}
\sometext

% Chapter with different table of contents entry
\chapter[Second in TOC]{Second}
\sometext

% Chapter with no table of contents entry
\chapter*{Third}
\sometext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome---thank you! So that's what \makeatletter does...

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Actually the suggestion doesn't reset the counters... I'll edit my post and post a MWE shortly.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I've updated my answer. See if it works for you now.

Comment: Goodness gracious that is wonderful! It works great. added the line `\setcounter{ex}{0}` (`ex` is my example environment) to reset the example counter at every chapter as well.